# Fetching Data from another table using foreign key laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 tables `attendance` and `student`. I am trying to retrieve my `stud_name` from `student` table by using the `student` foreign key in `attendance` table. I have a controller that return the view of all the results from `attendance` model. I have also added the relationship in both `student` and `attendance` model but whenever i try accessing the view i got an error exception of **Trying to get property 'stud_name' of non-object**. Anyone able to help me?

**AttendanceController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Attendance;

class GenerateReportController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $attendance = Attendance::with('student')->get();
        return view('generate')->with('attendance',$attendance);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**Student.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Student extends Model
{
   //Table
   protected $table = 'students';

   //Primary Key
   public $primaryKey = 'id';

   //Timestamps
   public $timestamp = true;

   public function programme(){
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Programme');
   }

   public function attendance(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Attendance');
   }
}
```

**Attendance.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Attendance extends Model
{
   //Table
   protected $table = 'attendance';

   //Primary Key
   public $primaryKey = 'id';

   //Timestamps
   public $timestamp = true;

   protected $fillable = [
        'att_status','date','time',
   ];

   public function student()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Student','s_id');
   }
```

**Blade File**

```
@foreach($attendance as $att)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$att->stud_Id->stud_name}}</td>
        //Other Data
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

**ADDITIONAL INFOMATION**

Student Table
[image: student table]

Attendance Table
[image: Attendance Table]

The reason all the primary key is named 'id' is because i am using voyager and it doesnt allow overriding of primary key name.

**dd($attendance)**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to make changes in this line of code

```
public function index()
{
    $attendance = Attendance::with('student')->get();
    return view('generate')->with('attendance',$attendance);
}


@foreach($attendance as $att)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$att->student->stud_name}}</td>
        //Other Data
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Attendance.php

```
public function student()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Student','stud_id');
}
```

Please let me know if you have any queries.

Comment: hi i have tried the changed of code u added but it seems like im getting an error "Method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all does not exist."

Comment: @DexterSiah Sorry my mistake, I have update the answer, please check and let me know

Comment: hi unfortunately i am still getting the error "Trying to get property 'stud_name' of non-object.". I have added some addtional pictures to show what is inside my student and attendance table hope u can help me thanks

Comment: @DexterSiah I've done the changes, please check and let me know

Comment: @DexterSiah please check error log file because there is no issue in this answer

Comment: @AvinashSinghRathi Yes i am stil getting the same error as before "Trying to get property 'stud_name' of non-object"

Comment: @JagjeetSingh the log file is mentioning the same error "Trying to get property 'stud_name' of non-object"

Comment: @DexterSiah I've update the answer. Please check and update me.

Comment: @JagjeetSingh Thank you! Log files are best for debugging.

Comment: @AvinashSinghRathi i have tried `<td>{{$att->student['stud_name'] }}</td>` the error didnt not show but it also did not show any data.

Comment: @DexterSiah Which is your foreign key in Attendance table for Student? Is it not s_id?

Comment: @AvinashSinghRathi its `stud_id` sorry `s_id` is for subject id

Comment: @DexterSiah I made the changes. Now check and update me

Comment: @AvinashSinghRathi it still does not show any data at the table but there are no errors

Comment: @DexterSiah just change the blade with the above code. I've update the answer

Comment: @AvinashSinghRathi whenever i change back to `$att->student->stud_name` i will get back the error `Trying to get property 'stud_name' of non-object`

Comment: @DexterSiah now just do onething: in Attendance model, where use student_ID instead of stud_id . Please check and update me

Comment: @AvinashSinghRathi you mean like this? `return $this->belongsTo('App\Student','student_ID');` if so, no it doesnt work... still displaying the same error

Comment: @AvinashSinghRathi hi sir i found out the reason it wasn't working instead of `stud_id` it was `stud_Id` the database automatically UPPERCASE the letter `i`. Thank you for your help sir case close

Comment: @DexterSiah I've done what I can instruct from here. I think, your code wanted to be inspected by us.

Comment: @DexterSiah Great! Atlast.. its done.. Now I'm alive :) Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanna try:

```
@foreach($attendance as $att)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$att->student->stud_name}}</td>
        //Other Data
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Also check out the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships).

In addition: I personally wouldn't call the property on the model `student` that holds the name `stud_name`. I'd call it `name`: the fact that it's a students name should be clear from the model name in combination with the name `name`.

Comment: @Nielles sorry but im ensure of what u meant by not naming it stud_name instead of name. Because i am using laravel + voyager i am worried that if any changes i made in the model might affect my other tables

Comment: @DexterSiah First of all, did this solution work? 2nd: What I meant is: you have a model called `student`. This student has a name, for me it would be logical to call this property (both in the model and in the database) `name` and not `stud_name`. It should be clear from the fact that it's a students name that this is a `stud(ents)_name`. It's more of a style thing, that might be nice to keep in mind for the future. It might also have too many implications for your current code to change this... although you should be able to refactor most automatically with a decent IDE.

Comment: @Nielles unfortunately no the solution didnt work for me i still had the same error stating "Trying to get property of non-object". Alright understood i will change into `name` in my database but how would i change it in the model? Do i need to declare my column names in all my model too? Sorry for asking such a question im still new and doing this for an assignment

Comment: You don't necessarily need to declare these names in your model, eloquent (part of Laravel) does this automatically... The properties that you can access in a retrieved model will change though. I am thinking there's something wrong with your database scheme (i.e. migration), more specifically that the foreign keys aren't correctly defined, causing eloquent to not correctly define the relationship. Can you post the relevant parts of `dd($att)` as well as the way you created your database table(s) (migration, probably/hopefully).

Comment: Additionally: "_Remember, Eloquent will automatically determine the proper foreign key column on the Comment model. By convention, Eloquent will take the "snake case" name of the owning model and suffix it with _id. So, for this example, Eloquent will assume the foreign key on the Comment model is post_id._" may be an interesting part from the docs, as well as the rest of the [documentation on relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships).

Comment: @Nielles I have added the dd data as for the migration tables i did not made any migration as i used voyager's database and BREAD system to implement the tables